# Sci Fi book about a miner who worked in space

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I bought a book from a Meijer grocery store in late 90's early 2000's.  It was a sci fi book about a human miner that worked in space blasting up large meteors that were heading towards their space station.  The humans worked with a subservient species of aliens who resembled bears (thinking teddy bears but human sized) that were incapable of making decisions on their own.  The station is attacked by an aggressive alien species.  The main bear alien character that worked with the human main character finally broke their natural tendency to be timid to stand up to the attacking aliens to save members of his species.  I don't remember the main human character very much other than he was male.  The cover was mostly blue and purple in color.  Hoping someone can tell me the name and or author cause I really want to read this again.  Thanks for any help!